# Replace all in multiple CSV - Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm attempting to replace the hostname from inside a CSV file with a blank space " ", but I am struggling to understand how this works, as when I attempt to call $env:computername it takes it as a string rather than the variable as per below:

```
$var = $env:computername
[io.file]::readalltext("C:\test\test.csv").replace("$var"," ") | Out-File c:\test\test-new.csv -Encoding ascii –Force
```

I have tested this and can see that the script is looking for the string $var in the CSV rather than the variable. Ultimately I would like to run this against a directory of CSV files that contain different hostnames in them and output the newly edited files to a separate location also.

Comment: FYI This code worked fine for me as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the quotes and tested this script and it worked for my test csv file

The quotes should be expanding the variable but if not you can simply pass the environmental variable directly like so:

```
[io.file]::readalltext("C:\test\test.csv").replace($env:ComputerName,"") | Out-File c:\test\test-new.csv -Encoding ascii –Force
```